# Opamp loop gain

Tags: operational-amplifier

I'm studying Negative Feedback of opamp, but I can't figure out how to calculate loop gain  $$A\beta$$ I know that it is necessary to break loop and use test generator, but I don't know exactly how it is done. Any suggestion?

Comment: In what circuit?

Comment: Is method for calculating loop gain valid in general, or it depends on specific circuit?

Comment: This should help you: http://www.daycounter.com/Calculators/Op-Amp/Op-Amp-Voltage-Calculator.phtml

Comment: Well the tricky part is usually identifying the forward gain part and the feedback part, which depends on the circuit.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Yes - if you can identify the main loop (sometimes there are, in addition, local loops) you have nothing to do than to open the loop at **any location** for injecting a test signal. However, you have to ensure two important points:

(1) You must not destroy/influence/change the dc operating point of the amplifier because often the feedback loop is active for DC also (that means: for fixing the DC quiescent point).

(2) You must not change the loading at the opening point. For this reason it is good to find a breaking point in the loop where a low-resistive output node (for example opamp output) meets a high-resistive load. If such a point cannot be found you have to create an image of the disconnected load and connect it to the opening point instead of the disconnected load.

(3) There is a kind of "trick" to circumvent the problem with the DC operating point: (a) Use a very large inductor between the opening ports (keeps the DC operating point, but opens the loop for signals above a low cut-off frequency) and (b) use a very large capacitor for injecting the test signal. The price for this "trick" is as follows: The loop gain is correct - except for very low frequencies (due to the inductor and the coupling capacitor) - however, in most cases this is not a problem because the loop gain flattens out for low frequencies and can be continued down to 0 Hz.
However, the possible problem with the disconnected load (isolated due to the inductor) still exists.

(4) There is another correct - however, somewhat complicated - method for simulating the loop gain introduced by Middlebrook: Using a test voltage source as well as a test current source. Then, both simulation runs must be combined. This is the most exact method - however, in most cases it is not necessary to determine the loop gain with such accuracy.